# Vectorized method for time-weighted mean according to specified weighting function

Tags: r

I'm looking to calculate a time-weighted mean using a specific weighting function in a vectorized manner.

I've figured out how to do this in a for loop (code below), but I'm working with datasets of appx 100k rows and I'm hoping to find a vectorized method. I've suspect this requires something from the `apply()` family, and have tried and failed to build a function that does this that would work in an `apply()`. I've written a function that (I think?) vectorizes the solution, but I'm not sure I've done it correctly or efficiently, and I was hoping there was a better solution out there.

EDIT: `txhousing` can be found in the `ggplot2` package

### build the dataset:

```r
library("tidyverse")

normal_fn <- function(x, mu = 0, theta_sq = 1){
  y <- (1 / sqrt(2 * pi * theta_sq)) * exp((-1*((x - mu)^2)) / (2 * theta_sq))

  return(y)
}

last_n <- 50

weights_df <- data.frame(weight = normal_fn(seq(0, 3, length.out = last_n)),
                         rank = seq(last_n))

txhousing.mutated <- txhousing %>% 
  filter(city %in% c("Austin", "Houston", "El Paso")) %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::as_date(paste0(year, "-", month, "-01"))) %>% 
  select(city, listings, date) %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(date_rank = rank(date))
```

### method 1: for loop

```r
tw_txhousing.list <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(txhousing.mutated))
for(i in seq(nrow(txhousing.mutated))){

  txhousing.this <- txhousing.mutated %>% 
    filter(city == txhousing.mutated[[i, "city"]] & date_rank < txhousing.mutated[[i, "date_rank"]]) %>% 
    arrange(date_rank) %>% 
    tail(last_n) %>% 
    mutate(this_date_rank = rev(row_number()))

  tw_txhousing.list[[i]] <- txhousing.this %>% 
    left_join(weights_df, by = c("this_date_rank" = "rank")) %>% 
    summarise(tw_listings = weighted.mean(listings, w = weight, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    mutate(date = txhousing.mutated[[i, "date"]])

}

tw_txhousing.df2 <- txhousing.mutated %>% 
  left_join(data.table::rbindlist(tw_txhousing.list), by = c("city", "date"))
```

### method 2: rowwise fn

```r
semi_vec <- function(data_df, weights, id, rank, prev){
  txhousing.this <- txhousing.mutated %>% 
    filter(city == id & date_rank < rank) %>% 
    arrange(date_rank) %>% 
    tail(last_n) %>% 
    mutate(this_date_rank = rev(row_number()))

  data.out <- txhousing.this %>% 
    left_join(weights_df, by = c("this_date_rank" = "rank")) %>% 
    summarise(tw_listings = weighted.mean(listings, w = weight, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    pull(tw_listings)

  if(length(data.out)<1){
    data.out <- NA_real_
  }

  return(data.out)
}

tw_txhousing.df <- txhousing.mutated %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(tw_listings = semi_vec(data_df = txhousing.mutated, weights = weights_df, id = city, rank = date_rank, prev = last_n)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

I expect to get the same results as those shown above, just in a faster time period. I've used a simple example, but it would be helpful if the function allowed for multiple outputs (say, weighted.mean(na.rm = F) as well as (na.rm = T), in the form of a list or multiple columns, whichever is easiest).

Thanks!

Comment: The "apply"-family does not provide vectorization. They are just syntactic sugar over for-loops. I'm not seeing a [MCVE] here. `txhousing` and `weights_df` and a bunch of other stuff are not visible.

Comment: `txhousing` is data from the `ggplot2` package, sorry, I should have noted that, `weights_df `is calculated in the code (see the Build the Dataset section). Maybe not "apply"-family, something in the purrr world? I just mean a vectorized solution- I'm unsure whether my second solution does that

Comment: I've attempted to figure out what equivalents might exist but reading other peoples code can be difficult when there are no natural language descriptions of the steps and ultimate goals. Apparently some people think that tidyverse code is self-documenting, but I do not find that to be the case.

Comment: No need to be like that, I see your criticism and I'll try to document my code more in the future. It felt like it would add clutter to an already too long question, but I may have been mistaken. If you have a specific question, I can clarify. Otherwise, I appreciate the time you spent trying to answer my question; hopefully next time I will ask in a more productive fashion.